# How to run an existing cake php project in my local using xampp server in windows

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

This is my webroot .htaccess file

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
    RewriteBase http://localhost/myproject/$1 [R=301,L]
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

This is project folder .htaccess file

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    #RewriteEngine on
    #RewriteRule    ^(\.well-known/.*)$ $1 [L]
    #RewriteRule    ^$    webroot/    [L]
    #RewriteRule    (.*) webroot/$1    [L]
    </IfModule>
```

This file is in app folder .htaccess file

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule    ^$    webroot/    [L]
RewriteRule    (.*) webroot/$1    [L]
</IfModule>
```

Can any one help me out with this?

Comment: You need to explain what you want to do (it seems you want to publish CakePHP in a subdirectory and share the virtual host with other apps, but it isn't entirely clear) and how your current set-up fails you meet your expectations.

Answer (score 0):

Try with below htaccess codes

/var/www/app/webroot/.htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

/var/www/app/.htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule    ^$    webroot/    [L]
    RewriteRule    (.*) webroot/$1    [L]
</IfModule>
```

/var/www/.htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule ^$ app/webroot/ [L]
    RewriteRule (.*) app/webroot/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: This page isn’t working Http error 500 getting this error

Comment: Please enable mod_rewrite in your xampp settings. you can change that from your php.ini file. restart xampp after doing changes

Answer (score 0):

There can be following reasons for 500 Internal Server Error in CakePHP application:

```
1) Your .htaccess files are not correct.
2) Permissions of folders are not correct. If CakePHP app is Group Writable i.e. 777 then webserver gives 500 error for safety.
3) You are missing Database Connection. Correct database configuration according to Webhost because most of times local and production server databases have different details.
4) Delete the content of your tmp folder. It is best practice that you must delete cache if you move your application from one place to another.
5) For testing purpose debug should be on like configure::write('debug',2);
6) If not succeeded check your Apache Error Log. If using Linux /var/log/apache2/error.log
```

Hope It Helps, Thanks!!